# Spreading an array in a typescript function: Error TS2556

Tags: typescript, spread-syntax

I am trying to use the spread-operator on a typescript-function call like this:

```js
function foo(x: number, y: number, z: number) {
  console.log(x + y + z);
}
const args = [0, 1, 2];
foo(...args);
```

But on compilation, I get the error: "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter" (TS2556). What am I doing wrong?

**Addendum**: How can I approach the problem when my argument is a dynamic array, as in

```js
const args = new Array(3).map(() => Math.random());
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Edit for dynamically generated `args`:

Option one: use type assertion if you are sure `args` will always be 3 elements tuple.

```
const args = new Array(3).map(() => Math.random()) as [number, number, number];
```

Option two, define `foo` to accept rest parameter:

```
function foo(...args: number[]) {
  console.log(args[0] + args[1] + args[2]);
}
const args = new Array(3).map(() => Math.random());
foo(...args);
```

---

Old answer for predefined `args`

You can assert args as const:

```
const args = [0, 1, 2] as const;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBZJcWCoCjwLzJeDwAAUq3yg3YiGkP34eHZnE53LI-AAXvzBT8AJSgADeihKCE4gng7gC0HgzFZoAA1KA8DrQCLJQBuRQAX0UisENEczGEAF5QABtAAM-AAjPwAEwAXTEwitqFNikZLIC4dtghNwWCKhwDQ8ZC8iHgAwYIPYNG+bjMzHYDGYkH4sGg6kS6fgehEXgARABRVYMRA1fQ1pI4mvgByoADkwgAcpAJDWgioAPLfMi7QRFrSQY6oRwKVzSfVOFM6UZYfQoBCIGHCK7ZiSp6IiAwcHHdFhsLjcIIlIA)

Or define args as tuple as the error suggested:

```
const args: [number, number, number] = [0, 1, 2];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=50&pln=13&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBZJcWCoCjwLzJeDwAAUq3yg3YiGkP34eHZnE53LI-AAXvzBT8AJSgADeihKCE4gng7gC0HgzFZoAA1KA8DrQCLJQBuRQAX0UisENEczAKoAA2gKuTyOS7hW6hQBdUAAXkdAAZ+ABGfgAJi9psUjJZATjtsEJuCwRUOAaHjIXkQ8AGDBB7Bo3zcZmY7AYzEg-Fg0HUiTz8D0Ii8ACIAKKrBiIGr6ZtJHHN8AOVAAcmEADlIBJm0EVAB5b5kXaCStaSDHVCOBSuaT6pzZnSjLD6FAIRAw4RXIsSHPREQGDg47osNhcbhBEpAA)

This is to guarantee that number / type of elements in `args` always match what's required by the function parameters.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it turned out that my minimal example was too minimal - my initialization of the args array is more complex -- I it is truly an array (see edit). But your explanation already helps me understanding the underlying issue -- I guess, since Arrays are mutable, there is no easy way to statically guarantee that the array-size matches, right?

Comment: Yeah if you can't  guarantee the input size of `args` then you need to define function parameters to be rest type so it also accepts indefinite number of parameters.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**const assertion**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to get rid of the problem. Because the function `foo` expects exactly 3 parameters:

```
function foo(x: number, y: number, z: number) {
  console.log(x + y + z);
}

const args = [0, 1, 2] as const;
foo(...args);
```

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically inferred param sizes, the `as const` method doesn't work.

Another solution is to use the array resulting from `...args` in an `.apply()` call. Typescript doesn't complain about this:

```
export class CustomError<
  ErrorCode extends keyof typeof CustomError.codes,
  ErrorParams extends Parameters<typeof CustomError.codes[ErrorCode]>
> extends Error {
  constructor(public code: ErrorCode, ...args: ErrorParams) {
    super(CustomError.codes[code].apply(null, args))
  }

  static codes = {
    invalidEmail (email: string) {
      return `Email ${email} is invalid`
    },
    invalidPasswordConfirm: (a: string, b: string) {
      return `Password ${a} and confirm ${b} are different`
    }
  }
}

new CustomError('invalidEmail', 'aaa@bbb')
// ^ CustomError(code: "invalidEmail", email: string)
new CustomError('invalidPasswordConfirm', 'first', 'second')
// ^ CustomError(code: "invalidPasswordConfirm", a: string, b: string)
```

Comment: I believe your answer only works because `.apply(thisArg, args)` is not strongly typed, for historic reasons, unless you use the `strictBindCallApply` option.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments don’t work in that way, this is how you should use them:

```
function multiply(n, ...m) {
    return m.map((x) => n * x);
}
// 'a' gets value [10, 20, 30, 40]
const a = multiply(10, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score -3):

Whoever suffers from `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.`, you might want to check whether `typescript-parser` is install in your devDependencies.