# TypeScript: How to use "...arguments" in class constructor to pass down all args into another function?

Tags: typescript

`test.js`:

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    this.init(...arguments);
  }
  init(arg, opts) {
    console.log(arg, opts);
  }
}
```

The above is perfectly valid JavaScript ES6 code. In TypeScript, you'd define the argument types:

`test.ts`:

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    this.init(...arguments);  // this no worky
  }
  init(arg: string, opts: Object) {
    console.log(arg, opts);
  }
}
```

But the typescript version has a problem with `this.init(...arguments);`. It complains `(local var) arguments: IArguments A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)`.

How do I pass down "all arguments no matter what" down to the sub function, while avoiding the ugly `apply(this, args)` construct?

I know I could specifically name all parameters, given that there are 2 here, but let's assume in my real application, both `constructor()` and `init()` must be able to accept a huge amount of parameters. Even if all parameters were known, it's tedious and verbose to repeat all parameters *and their types* in typescript, over and over, in each cascading sub function call level, when you already know they will only be passed down and handled by sub function `init()` *anyway*.

---

It was suggested that this [Spreading an array in a typescript function: Error TS2556](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884073/spreading-an-array-in-a-typescript-function-error-ts2556) already answers this question. So I tried this:

`test2.ts`:

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor (...args: any[]) {
    this.init(...args);  // STILL throws the TS2556 error
  }
  init(arg: string, opts: Object) {
    console.log(arg, opts);
  }
}
```

It still throws the TS2556 error.

Comment: `constructor (…params: any[])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spreading an array in a typescript function: Error TS2556](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884073/spreading-an-array-in-a-typescript-function-error-ts2556)

Comment: With constructor `(...args: any[])` still `this.init(...args);` throws the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there's not enough information for TypeScript to be sure about the correctness of the types: `arguments` is not properly typed, and `...args: any[]` is explicitly saying "an array with some number of whatever". You have to add this information by yourself, and you can do this with the built-in `Parameters` helper:

```
constructor (...args: Parameters<MyClass["init"]>) {
  this.init(...args);
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/mMxpbN).*

Comment: How would I use the `Parameters` helper to get the parameters of the superclass's constructor? I tried `constructor (...args: Parameters<MySuperClass["constructor"]>) { super(...args); }` but it fails with `Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any): any'.ts(2344)`. `Parameters<MySuperClass["MySuperClass"]>` gets me back to the TS2556 error.

Comment: For that there's `ConstructorParameters<MySuperClass>`